# VB.Net JSON "Is Nothing" returns wrong value when serializing

Tags: json, vb.net

```
item.Text = If(jResults2("items")("item") Is Nothing, "", jResults2("items")("item")("icon").ToString())
```

If item is not present in the json it will continue. However when the item does appear in the json, it is still setting the "" value rather than the value provided by json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. To inspect it more closely at runtime, try to run your application in debug mode, put breakpoint at that line of code. Then see in VS's watch window what value each of following expression returns :

- `jResults2("items")("item")`
- `jResults2("items")("item") Is Nothing`
- `jResults2("items")("item")("icon").ToString()`

With that you can be sure what is happening. Train your debugging skill, that will help a lot.

Comment: thanks i found the issue when the item was missing my json became invalid